# TCP и HTTP сервер в одном node.js сервере

Tags: node.js, tcp

Пишу приложение на node.js, которое является и http и tcp сервером. tcl сервер работает с определенными клиентами- посылает им команды и получает ответ.

Нужно:
При получении запроса по http - отправить команду на определенный клиент, получить от него ответ и отдать этот ответ в запросе по http. Все это нужно делать без блокирования, т.е. для обечпечения работы нескольких клиентов по http так и используя несколько tcp клиентов.

```
//http server

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);

//tcp server
    var clients = [];
    net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort
    clients.push(socket);
    socket.on('data', function (data) {});
    socket.on('error',function(error) {
        socket.end();
        console.log(error);
    });
    socket.on('close',function(had_error) {});
    socket.on('end', function () {console.log('onend');}); 
    }).listen(5000);
```

Т.е. нужно каким то образом пробрасывать response объект http в socket.on('data', function (data) {}); где происходит чтение из сокета tcp клиента.

Есть какие-то идеи как это сделать или какое-то архитектурное решение?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

**Дополнение:**

Я еще дополнительно должен считывать информацию от tcp клиентов и они проходят авторизацию на сервере. И только когда я отправляю им команду тогда жду сразу ответ

```
 socket.on('data', function (data) {

        var imei = data.toString("binary");
        //авторизация
        if (imei == 'xxxxxxxx') {
                var raw = '01';
                this.imei = imei;
                var now = new Date();

                var buff = new Buffer(raw, 'hex');
                socket.write(buff);
            }
        //клиент уже прошело авторизацию. шлет нам какие-то данные
        } else if(this.imei && (data.length == 3 || data.length == 6)) {

        } else if (data[0] == 4 && data[2] > 0) {

        } else if (this.imei && data.length > 3) {

      //и где-то здесь нужно нам, наверное, поймать ответ от клиента после посылки ему команды

    });
```

Comment: можно поточнее об "отправить команду на определенный клиент", по каким критериям он выбирается?

Comment: в запросе от http приходит id клиента tcp. Типы "отправь команду на такой tcp клиент - дождись ответа и отдай этот ответ по http"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//http server

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var sock_id = request. // достаете id сокета
  process(responce, sock_id); // и передаете в функцию 
}).listen(8888);

//tcp server
    var clients = {}; // лучше использовать объект для ассоциативной связи id и сокета
    net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;
    var id = ... // формируете id можно id = socket.name;
    clients[id] = socket;
    socket.on('error',function(error) {
        delete clients[socket];
        socket.end();
        console.log(error);
    });
    socket.on('close',function(had_error) {});
    socket.on('end', function () {console.log('onend');}); 
    }).listen(5000);

function process(responce, sock_id) {
  var sock = clients[sock_id];
  sock.once('data', onData); // это событие обработается единожды
  sock.write(''); // отправляете свою команду команду
  function onData(data) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end(data.toString());
  }
}
```

Как-то так, писал без ноды.

**Обновлено:**

```
var clients = {};
var request_queue = [];

var current_response = {};

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  // создаете свой запрос и заносите различные данные
  // такие как id сокета, команда и прочее
  var req = {
    response: responce,
    sock_id: ...,
    cmd: ...
  };
  // заносите его в очередь
  request_queue.unshift(req);
  // если очередь пустая (или первый запрос) выполняем его
  if (!request_queue.length) {
    next_request();
  }

}).listen(8888);

net.createServer(function (socket) {

  clients[sock_id] = socket;

  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    // проверяем авторизован ли сокет, нет - авторизуем
    if (!socket.imei) {
      auth(socket, data);
      return;
    }
    //клиент уже прошел авторизацию. шлет нам какие-то данные
    // тут их обрабатываете, и там где данные являются ответом, выполняете опр. действия
    if(data.length == 3 || data.length == 6) {

      return;
    }

    if (data[0] == 4 && data[2] > 0) {

      return
    }

    if (data.length > 3) {
      // например, тут
      // обрабатываете
      current_response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      current_response.write(data);
      // и переходите к следующему запросу
      next_request();
      return;
    }   
  });

  // все ошибки и таймауты обрабатываете сами

}).listen(5000);

function auth(sock, data) {
  var imei = data.toString("binary");

  if (imei != 'xxxxxxxx') 
    return sock.write(/*error_code*/);

  sock.imei = imei;
  var raw = '01';
  var buf = new Buffer(raw, 'hex');

  socket.write(buf);
}

function next_request() {
  // достаем данные запроса из очереди
  var req = request_queue.pop();
  var sock = clients[req.sock_id];
  current_response = req.response;

  sock.on('data', onData);
  sock.write(req.cmd);
}
```

Работоспособность не проверял, но думаю идея ясна, пилите под себя, идентификация сокетов и прочее.

Comment: ок. спасибо.
А если мне нужно еще дополнительно слушать по tcp что присылают клиенты.т.е постоянно слушать. Так как tcp-клиент проходит авторищацию и шлет другую информацию. и только когда я отправляю команду по tcp -  тогда ждать от этого tcp клиента ответа и отдавать по htpp, иначе слушать другую инфу с клиента и что-то там делать.

Comment: @programmer, два уточняющих вопроса: в момент отправки команды и получения результата, tcp socket отправляет какие-либо другие данные, не предназначенные для http клиента, сделавшего запрос? Может быть ситуация, когда, в непродолжительный промежуток времени, от разных клиентов сделано несколько запросов к одному и тому же tcp сокету в порядке 1, 2, 3, из-за различных задержек в сети и обработке данных, результаты пришли в хаотичном порядке (2, 1, 3)?

Comment: от http клиентов нужно создавать очередь. т.е. один tcp клиент выполняет команды только последовательно. т.е. http клиенты ждут когда дойдет до них очередь пока выполняется команда на этом tcp сокете от другого http клиента.Ну или http клиенты должны отпадать по timeout если прошло допустим больше 1 минуты как они подконнектились к серверу и ждут (т.е. не получили еще ответ от tcp клиента или до них очередь еще не дошла на отправку команды)  Т.е. команда на tcp сокет не посылается пока tcp клиент не ответит на предыдущую команду или если долго не отвечает или отконнектился.

Comment: но tcp сокет может еще отправлять другую информацию. не зависимо посылали ему команды или нет. Т.е. когда мы будем ждать ответ из сокета на команду - нужно проверять это ответ на команду или другая информация. Это проверяется легко. когда от отвечает то передает одни цифры, а когда просто шлет инфу то другие. Т.е. во время ожидания ответа может прийти другая информация, которую нужно не учитывать и ждать ответа.

Comment: @programmer, обновил

Comment: да. я все так примерно и представлял через специальную глобальную переменную current_response которая хранит текущий http ответ. 
у меня такой еще вопрос: что делает ф-йия onData?  и у нас получается два слушателя события сокета sock.on('data', onData); и socket.on('data',function(data) {}); ?

Comment: @programmer,строчка с onData - рудимент, удалите ее.